# How to map keybindings only for specific file type?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, neovim, filetype

In `vimwiki`, `<C-x><C-o>` provides available tags in autocomplete dropdown. I am attempting to map that key mapping to something easier like  (ctrl+alt+space) and only when I am in a markdown file. How can I accomplish such?

Things I have tried but didn't work:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <C-M-space> <C-x><C-o>
inoremap <buffer> <C-M-space> <C-x><C-o>

nnoremap <C-M-space> <C-x><C-o>
inoremap <C-M-space> <C-x><C-o>

autocmd! FileType markdown nnoremap <buffer> <C-M-space> <C-x><C-o>
autocmd! FileType markdown inoremap <buffer> <C-M-space> <C-x><C-o>

autocmd! FileType md nnoremap <buffer> <C-M-space> <C-x><C-o>
autocmd! FileType md inoremap <buffer> <C-M-space> <C-x><C-o>

map <buffer> <C-M-space> <C-x><C-o>
```

Comment: You need to use the `autocmd FileType markdown` you have, that one is fine. The problem is probably that mapping `Ctrl+Alt+Space` is hard/impossible in your terminal. On my terminal anyway that doesn't work. I'm not sure if there's a good solution for this.